# After crashing, alias has become an index

Tags: elasticsearch

Our cluster had 2 indexes, global5 and global6. It had one alias, global, which pointed to global5.

After a crash and restarting some nodes, our cluster got into this weird state:

```
http://localhost:9200/_aliases 
{
  "global": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "global6": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "global5": {
    "aliases": {
      "global": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Previously there was no index called global, just an alias.

The list of shards now shows 36, 12 for global5 and global6 (which are legitimate) and 12 unassigned ones for the 'ghost' index global.

I'm scared to delete the global index because I think it might drop global5, and I can't remove the alias (I get Invalid alias name [global], an index exists with the same name as the alias].)

Searches against the global alias return errors.

Comment: same thing happened to me

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old question, but do you remember if you ever found the culprit? We've experienced this too. Removing the index seems to be fine, but it's strange that it happens.